# SFML Drawing OpenGL to multiple windows extremely slow

Tags: c++, performance, sfml, frame-rate

Here is the situation:

I have 4 SFML windows, which are inside a container which I have built. The container calls independent redraw methods for each window, starting with the first and ending with the last.

If each window's drawing code contains the lines `drawMyCube()` OR `glClear(...)`, then the frame rate becomes slow.

`drawMyCube()` just draws a cube which rotates depending on the value of an sf::Clock object.

If one window calls (either of) these functions, the frame rate is ~60fps.
If two windows call (either of) these functions, the frame rate is ~30fps.
If three windows call (either of) these functions, the frame rate is ~20fps.
Finally, if all four call (either of) these functions, the frame rate is ~15fps.

This looks like a pattern emerging, so I tried removing the functions from 3 of the windows, and calling them 10 times from one window. I was expecting the frame rate to be ~6fps, but it remained at 60.

Does anyone know why this is happening? There doesn't seem to be any effect if I remove any other functions from the window drawing methods, for example, `gluLookAt()` doesn't seem to slow it down.

EDIT: Frame rate limit is set to zero and vsync is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds exactly like vertical sync.  Each of your windows is waiting for vertical refresh, which is why your rate keeps getting cut in half.

I know you said that vsync is off, but it's possible that your video driver is forcing it.  Check your driver settings.

Comment: Actually that sounds about right. I don't know how to do that using (X)Ubuntu Linux, which is running on a  MacBook-Pro.

I remember having a problem like this in the past, about a month ago, hence I ordered a new laptop with a real graphics processor in it. Still waiting for it though...

BUT: Is there any way in which I can get around this problem?

Comment: If the driver is forcing vsync, the only thing you can do is disable it in the driver.  From personal experience, the nvidia Linux driver seems to have a bug in this regard, and forces vsync by default.  I've found that launching and quitting the nvidia-settings app will turn it off.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - on launch I get the error message "you do not appear to be using a nvidia driver" - guess I am using an Intel one?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the details of your system.  Either way, this is a user controlled option, so if you plan to release this program to other people, there's no way to stop them from enabling global vsync.  The only way I can think of to handle this at the application level is to have a thread dedicated to each window so that they can sync in parallel, but I know that multithreaded OpenGL can be a tricky thing, and I have no personal experience in that.

Comment: Yeah I figure that would be impossible because you draw to a surface in video memory... and there is only one to draw to...